# How to programmatically create a topic in Apache Kafka using C++ client librdkafka

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, kafka-topic

So far I haven't seen a c++ client librdkafka that implements the creation of a topic explicitly without using the configuration option to create automatically the topics.

Comment: Look at the example code? https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp#L650

Comment: Or the documentation? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/classRdKafka_1_1Topic.html

Comment: Yes I will try this. Thanks for the reference doc.

Comment: In case someone is using modern-cpp-kafka library - https://github.com/morganstanley/modern-cpp-kafka/blob/main/include/kafka/AdminClient.h